# Spring Boot REST server not working on Ubuntu Server 14.04

Tags: java, spring, ubuntu, spring-boot

I have written a REST server with Spring Boot 1.3.1, it runs as expected on Windows 7 and Ubuntu Server 15.04. But it does not on Ubuntu Server 14.04, even all the unit tests are failing.

#### Reproduction of the problem

Because I was not sure if I forgot a setting on the US 14.04, I installed two virtual machines. One with Ubuntu Server 14.04 and one with Ubuntu Server 15.10.
Furthermore I installed Java 8 from the same [PPA](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java) and `java -version` shows the same version. Afterwards I installed Maven from the repository and cloned my git project. Then I ran `mvn clean install`.

This executes the unit tests, which fail on the VM US 14.04 with the same error message as on the US 14.04. On the VM US 15.10 the unit tests run through without a failure.

#### The error

In my REST server I load meta data (users, permissions, database connections) from one database and afterwards I load the actual data.
To separate this in the code I have two classes annotated with `@Configuration`: `MetadataConf` and `RealDataConf`.

`MetadataConf` is set in such way that a `UserRepository` is created. This is done with `@EnableJpaRepositories(entityManagerFactoryRef = "metaDataEntityManagerFactory", basePackages = "com.somename.data.metadata.repository",
transactionManagerRef = "metaDataTransactionManager")`

In `RealDataConf` the `UserRepository` is autowired.

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(repositoryFactoryBeanClass = ExtendedRepositoryFactoryBean.class,
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "realDataEntityManagerFactory",
                       basePackages = "com.somename.data.realdata.repository",
                       transactionManagerRef = "realDataTransactionManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class RealDataConf
{
  @Autowired
  UserRepository userRepository;

  // FooBar is a POJO and as not annotations
  @Bean
  FooBar foobar()
  {
    // ...
    if(userRepository == null)
    {
      throw new Exception("UserRepository must not be null.");
    }
    return new FooBar(userRepository);
  }

  // ...

}
```

I added the check for null to make the stack traces clearer, because otherwise a NPE is thrown later and creates a very long stack trace.
Anyhow on the US 14.04 machines this exception is always thrown, whereas on the other OSes the exception is not thrown. Thus for some reason the repository is not autowired, or injected as `null`.

The easiest solution is probably to upgrade Ubuntu. Or to switch to a newer kernel?
But on the other side I am worried that I made a mistake which might occur on the other OSes too.

(I posted as few code and explanations as possible to not bloat the question, if more code is needed, I will of course provide it)

#### Edit

I tried adding the repository as method parameter. Then I get the following error on US 14.04 when running the unit tests (With the modification on Win7 there is no problem):

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userRepository': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository interface must not be null on initialization!
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:175) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:127) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getObjectForBeanInstance(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1585) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:254) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1116) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1014) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 97 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Repository interface must not be null on initialization!
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.notNull(Assert.java:115) ~[spring-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.initAndReturn(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:248) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:199) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.getObject(RepositoryFactoryBeanSupport.java:47) ~[spring-data-commons-1.11.2.RELEASE.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:168) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        ... 106 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Instead of auto wiring the `userRepository` as a property just add it as a method argument for the `@Bean` method. `foobar(UserRepository userRepository)`. Then see if it still happens.

Comment: @M.Deinum please see my edit

Comment: Is your `FooBar` by any means annotated with `@Service` or the likes? Although not sure why it happens it looks like the correct methods aren't called in the right sequence. It is initializing things before the `FactoryBean` is setup correctly. Which is weird as it works on other systems...Intriguing issue :). Is the code you put on here correct as I see a `userRepository` and ` metadataUserRepository` as names.

Comment: Could you provide a minimal project which reproduces this issue? I suspect it is due to the fact that you have `@EnableJpaRepositories` yourself (and you are probably using multiple entity managers?) . Maybe the loading order changed in ubuntu/windows.

Comment: @M.Deinum yes, I will try that

Comment: And maybe you could try Spring boot 1.3.2 and explain a bit more on how many entitymanagers/datasources you use.

Comment: I tried Spring Boot 1.3.2, but it the same error occurs. Creating a minimal project and/or explaining will take some time.

Comment: I understand, but I'm intrigued by this :) although your solution might be to upgrade to Ubuntu 14.10 or 15.x I wonder why this happens (just for learning and fun experience :) ).

Comment: Yes, I think I will upgrade/reinstall Ubuntu and hope that it works as expected. And reproducing the problem will become my new weekend project. :)

Comment: @M.Deinum The REST server is finally running, but I am not sure why. Unfortunately I have no minimal project.

Answer (score 0):

#### Short Version

After some more research my colleague and I detected that on the faulty system the Bean creation order was wrong.

To make sure that the order is correct we added `@ComponentScan({"com.somename.first", "com.somename.second", "com.somename.third", "com.somename.forth"})` to our Application.
For some reason `@DependsOn` had no effect on the faulty system.

#### Long Version

We detected the wrong order by adding log outputs to the `@PostConstruct` and `@Bean` methods of our `@Configuration` classes. The order of the log entries was as expected on the working system, but out of order on the faulty system. Due to this the `UserRepository` could not have been built yet and is therefore `null`. Furthermore one `@Configuration` class did not appear in the logs at all.

In a first attempt we tried to use `@DependsOn`. To make sure that we use it correctly, we broke our application on the working system by inverting the dependencies of `@Configuration` classes. Afterwards we changed the annotation in the expected order, so that it worked again on the working system. But without success on the faulty system.

In a desperate attempt my colleague added `@ComponentScan` to our main class, giving it the order of the packages as parameter. The package `com.somename.first` contains the `@Configuration` class which must be built first and so on. This finally convinced the faulty system to create the `Bean`s in the desired order and the REST server runs as expected.

After all we have no idea why this behavior happens on one system and not on the other.

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = { DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
    JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class })
@ComponentScan({"com.somename.first", "com.somename.second", "com.somename.third", "com.somename.forth"})
public class Application
{
  static ConfigurableApplicationContext c;

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    c = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
}
```